# Open file in vertical split in Vim / netrw

Tags: vim

If I open vim with `vim .` netrw provides me with a nice list of the files and directories in the current directory.

If I open a file using `v` the file opens in a very narrow split down the left hand side of the screen and the directory listing remains open in a wide split on the right hand side of the screen.

Ideally I'd like it to have the opposite effect. ie. Show the directory listing in a narrow split on the left hand side of the screen and show the file in a wide split on the right hand side of the screen.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy. Put the following line in your .vimrc and restart vim:

```
let g:netrw_altv=1
```

See `:he netrw-v`, `:he g:netrw_altv`.

In current session simply run the command.